# How do you escape the prison?

Tags: cipher, computer-puzzle

You are a wrongly-accused prisoner in a high-security prison, where you have been sentenced for life. However, one of the guards believes your story, and has given you a single chance to escape. He has told you that there is a special word you can say to the man at the gate, and he will gladly open the way out for you. The same day, you found a cryptic bit of paper underneath your bed. The paper reads as follows:

```
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
```

You realise this must be the guard trying to give you a clue of how to escape, or what the secret word is, but you have no idea what it means. You also know that the man at the gate will not hesitate to kill anyone who speaks the incorrect password.

You get one shot at this, so you walk up to the gatekeeper. What should you say to him?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To finish off the great work done by [ABcDexter](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/35546/1777) and f''

You should say to the guard:

> Hello World!

These lines:

> `Give me 5!`
>  `-----------------------------------////++++++++////`
>  `/+++++++++/+++++++++++++/++++/-////*/`
>  `./---.+++++++..+++././/////+++++++++++++++./.+++.------.--------./+.`

Are a hint to use the:

> Esoteric programming language [HighFive](https://esolangs.org/wiki/HighFive)

I wrote the following interpreter:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

string s;
int a[256][5], seg, ptr, lastmod;

int main() {
    cin >> s;
    for(int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++) {
        if(s[i] == '+') {
            a[seg][ptr]++;
            lastmod = a[seg][ptr];
        }
        else if(s[i] == '-') {
            a[seg][ptr]--;
            lastmod = a[seg][ptr];
        }
        else if(s[i] == '/')
            ptr = (ptr + 1) % 8;
        else if(s[i] == '*') {
            if(lastmod != 0) {
                i += a[seg][ptr];
                i--;
            }
        }
        else if(s[i] == '.')
            cout << (char)a[seg][ptr];
        else
            cout << "oops" << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

It's not exactly accurate as the memory size of int is bigger than a byte, but for this purpose it's ok.

Comment: Took me the longest time to figure out how the '*' worked.  Once I figured out it was keeping an extra variable for the last modified value, then I had it.

Comment: I did the segmenting wrong.  Oh well.  When I get some time I might update it.

Comment: ... Well now I don't understand how OP said the answer is one word yet still accepted this?

Comment: @feelinferrety It's possible that he didn't execute the code segment that he copied from the Wiki page.  The caption for it is HELLO.

Comment: @feelinferrety I was going to answer with that but my inner-nerd took over and saw that there were more than 5 full stops in the code.

Comment: I have yet to get into esolangs (I know what they are now!) so I couldn't tell, but I trust your answer as I know you to be an exceptional solver.  Besides, code interpretation is code interpretation. I'm just marveling over the ... (sorry I can't put this nicely) bungling of that particular tidbit on OP's part. Like... don't give a hint you don't know is right.

Answer (score 2):

A simple

> HEX to ASCII

conversion shows this

> `Give me 5!`
>  `-----------------------------------////++++++++////`
>  `/+++++++++/+++++++++++++/++++/-////*/`
>  `./---.+++++++..+++././/////+++++++++++++++./.+++.------.--------./+.`
>  `I'm stuck on the fence between 3 train tracks!`
>  `Tgt 3h@.h r31gpv5tewy.33n@  .`

As [f''](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/12408/f) hinted in comments:

> There is hint of Rail fence cipher

in this

> `I'm stuck on the fence between 3 train tracks!`

In this

> I used the rail fence decoder and with 3 as the key

The result is:

> **..Th3 gr33t1ng p@v35 the w@y.**

So, my final(hopefully) answer is:

> As in the first line `Give me 5!` as [high-five](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_five), but here it's $5!$ i.e. $120$.
>  So, I will say **120** or just give a high-five.

Comment: I suggest you look at the Hex to ASCII more closely, it isn't that simple.

Comment: Also, the guard said that it was a single _word_...

Comment: @GeorgeGibson Please look at the updated answer.

Comment: Nope, it's one word.

Comment: "fence" and "train tracks" is an obvious clue for a railfence cipher.

Comment: @f'' Yes, and that can be used to decypher the last line.

Comment: Getting closer, but what is 'The greeting'?

Comment: Please see the final answer. I'm probably over-thinking :/

Comment: Argh, you're so close!!

Comment: That seemingly random series of punctuation does have some significance...

Comment: @GeorgeGibson Yes, I pondered over them, but what came me my mind was a "star" as in 5 star and an asterisk in between the two forward slashes in the middle line.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40948/discussion-between-george-gibson-and-abcdexter).

Comment: Maybe the punctuation is a brainf**k program

Comment: No, [it's not](http://ideone.com/MwIUBN)...

Comment: @ev3commander You're not far off thinking about Esolangs though...

Comment: Ok, is it one of "those" languages :/

Comment: @ABcDexter Yes, and the greeting does indeed pave the way.  Combine these two things and you'll find the answer.  If you don't, I'll post the answer later.

Comment: @LeppyR64 I completely forgot that I've attempted this question. Your answer is perfect. The last time I used these languages was WhiteSpace "something in here" :)